# undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run the rails application, I get the following error:

> undefined local variable or method "config" for main:Object

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Is this displaying in the console, or a log? Please post the entire backtrace. Also post the code which the backtrace points you to.

Comment: I don't know anything about Ruby on Rails, but I know enough about programming to know that good programming questions should include code.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you found some code examples from an older version of rails, which called for you to place a config.gem * in your environment.rb file.  To fix this add the gem requirement to your gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

in your enviroment.rb file, cut any line starting with config and paste into your production.rb/development.rb/test.rb instead.

This is what worked for me when I had a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when an application had been upgraded from Rails 2 to Rails 3.  It worked in development but I got this error when running in production mode for the first time because `config/environments/production.rb` contained Rails 2-style lines such as:

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

..which needed converting to Rails 3-style:

```rb
<<NameOfYourApp>>::Application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true
end
```