# Cannot run rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When trying to run `rails s` getting the error as shown in [figure](http://i43.tinypic.com/2u7q0yr.jpg)

```
undefined local variable or methode 'config' for main:Object (NameError)
```

My application.rb file :

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

Comment: See if this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10075976

Comment: @user2503775 I saw that post earlier, didn't help

Comment: Please attach the file development.rb

Comment: @user2503775 there you are [figure] (http://i41.tinypic.com/2nktpc1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're running 3.x (or probably 4.x, but i don't know if it changed in fourth revision of RoR) you need to write something like this:

```
module RailsApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
  end
end
```

In Rails 2.x it w'd be:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
end
```

That's of course only relevan part of the file, you should also include all other parts, but above code (or rather lack of it) is the cause of your problem.

Comment: I love you man, you saved me !